# How do clicks from Google Places show up in Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, local-seo, google-local-search, google-places

We've just implemented Google Places for our business and are getting a few hits through the mini-analytics that places have. But those are just a hybrid impressions, CTR chart.

Is there a way to track clicks from local results in the full blown Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very lengthy article discussing a number of ways to track Google Places data in Google Analytics. It's far too long to repost here

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/tracking-traffic-from-google-places-in-google-analytics